# Why the variable inside of useEffect "delays" updating its value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const previousInputValue = useRef("");

  useEffect(() => {
    previousInputValue.current = inputValue;
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <h2>Current Value: {inputValue}</h2>
      <h2>Previous Value: {previousInputValue.current}</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am having trouble to understand how previousInputValue.current is able to yield the previous value of inputValue instead of its current one.
The way I am seeing this is, as soon as you type something in input, it updates "inputValue" then re-renders the component, but the change of variable triggers useEffect which, in turn, updates previousInputValue. And here lies my doubt, that "inputvalue" inside useEffect doesn't get the current value (that was updated during the first re-render)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And here lies my doubt, that "inputvalue" inside useEffect doesn't get the current value

Because `useRef` changes **do not affect** the React component lifecycle (does not re-render the component). The value of `useRef` is updated **after** component re-render and **after** `useEffect` call.

```
input value change ->
     component state change ->
          component re-renders and still displays old value of useRef ->
              useEffect is triggered and changes the useRef value

            // ^^^ the new value of useRef won't be visible until next re-render
```

Comment: "the new value of useRef won't be visible until next re-render" -> This is not really true: it would be visible if user did console.log inside useEffect of the ref value. But since it is in JSX, it needs a re-render to reflect change.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava "Won't be visible" - I mean that it will not be displayed by the component (the old value will be displayed instead).